# I have downloaded a fastq file from SRA and I have problems reading it into my workspace. Is there another way for reading fastq files into R?

Tags: r, bioconductor

> fqsample <- readFastq("/cloud/project/sra_data.fastq.", pattern = "fastq")
>   Error: Input/Output
>     no input files found
>     dirPath: /cloud/project/sra_data.fastq.
>     pattern: fastq

Comment: are you sure that the path is correct? Your filename ends with a `.` (`/cloud/project/sra_data.fastq.`)

Comment: @ fra, thank you for pointing that out. I have edited it and tried again, but still not working

Comment: not sure if sra provides fastq files. Either you download them from https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena or you need to install sratoolkit (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK158900/), use fastq-dump to uncompress them and get the fastq

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your path or filename is wrong.

Is the . at the end of your filename (.fastq.) intentional or a typo?

Try it without the .:

```
fqsample <- readFastq("/cloud/project/sra_data.fastq", pattern = "fastq")
```

**Edit**

I have just tried the readFastq function myself on a single file. You don't need to specify `pattern = "fastq"`.

To explain it in more detail, you could read your file in two ways:

`readFastq("/cloud/project/", pattern = "sra_data.fastq")`

Here the first argument is just the path and the second is the file name. If you only provide the path, it would read all files inside the directory.

or:

`readFastq("/cloud/project/sra_data.fastq")`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ MKR, Many thanks for pointing that out. I've tried it but it still returns the same error message. Could there be a problem with the fastq file? This is the first time I have downloaded an SRA file

Comment: see my edid in the answer